# Amazon CloudFormation How to delete specific stack events and rerun them

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am running a stack on cloudformation that creates some resources like Route53, etc...
I want to be able to recreate only some of the resources with the same value.

for example, One of the stack events creates image on ECR and I want to rebuild it. Run rollback on that event and then create it again with the same parameters.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to specify parts of a stack to 'rebuild'.

For some resources, you can **modify an attribute to trigger a redeployment**. The documentation will say `Update requires: Replacement`.

For other resources, you could:

- Remove the resource from the template file
- **Update** the stack with the template, which will cause CloudFormation to attempt to remove the resource (if it still exists)
- Restore the template to the previous contents
- **Update** the stack again, which will **cause CloudFormation to deploy the 'new' resources**

Comment: It's not exactly what I did but its close enough, I added a condition for the events I wanted to recreate using a parameter and I just use the same template and turn those params on and off